# Как в 1С-Битрикс отобразить инфоблок?

Tags: php, битрикс

Добрый день.

Есть инфоблок в битриксе с разделами, где в каждом разделе ещё разделы и товары.

Как это вывести визуально?

Спасибо.

Comment: @Роман Ракзин, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Если инфоблок является торговым каталогом, то создаётся отдельный раздел с компонентом bitrix:catalog в index.php. В настройках компонента должен быть указан соответствующий тип инфоблоков и сам инфоблок.

http://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/user_help/content/iblock/components_2/catalog/catalog.php

Если инфоблок не является таковым, то аналогичным образом используется компонент bitrix:news.

http://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/user_help/content/iblock/components_2/news/news.php